# EventHandler registered with Mouse.AddPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementHandler never hits

Tags: c#, wpf, events

So I'm trying to build a drop down color picker custom control. I currently have it set so when I click the rectangle part the popup part opens. I would like to have it so when I click anywhere outside the control the popup closes. I wrote a `MouseButtonEventHandler` and registered it with `Mouse.AddPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementHandler`. However, the handler never hits no matter where I click in the window. I find it odd because there's two controls in the WPF Toolkit that utilize this method. The two being the [DropDownButton](https://github.com/Emudofus/BehaviorIsManaged/tree/master/Librairies/WPFToolkit.Extended/DropDownButton) Control and the [CalculatorUpDown](https://github.com/Emudofus/BehaviorIsManaged/tree/master/Librairies/WPFToolkit.Extended/CalculatorUpDown) Control. Am I missing anything that would prevent the handler from firing?

Control Code:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = DisplayColorPart, Type = typeof(Rectangle))]
[TemplatePart(Name = DropDownPart, Type = typeof(Popup))]
public class ColorPickerDropDown : Control
{
    private const string DisplayColorPart = "PART_DisplayColor";
    private const string DropDownPart = "PART_DropDown";


    private Rectangle _displayColorElement;
    private Popup _dropDownElement;


    public Rectangle DisplayColorElement
    {
        get { return _displayColorElement; }
        set
        {
            _displayColorElement = value;
            InitalizeDisplayColorElement();
        }
    }

    public Popup DropDownElement
    {
        get { return _dropDownElement; }
        set { _dropDownElement = value; }
    }



    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(ColorPickerDropDown),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public Brush CurrentColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(CurrentColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentColorProperty, value); }
    }



    static ColorPickerDropDown()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty
            .OverrideMetadata(typeof (ColorPickerDropDown),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (ColorPickerDropDown)));
    }

    public ColorPickerDropDown()
    {
        Mouse.AddPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementHandler(this, OutsideControlClick);
    }



    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (DisplayColorElement == null) DisplayColorElement = GetTemplateChild(DisplayColorPart) as Rectangle;
        if (DropDownElement == null) DropDownElement = GetTemplateChild(DropDownPart) as Popup;
    }


    private void InitalizeDisplayColorElement()
    {
        if (DisplayColorElement == null) return;

        DisplayColorElement.AddHandler(Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
                                       new RoutedEventHandler(DisplayColorClick),
                                       handledEventsToo: true);
    }

    private void DisplayColorClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownElement.IsOpen = DropDownElement.IsOpen ? false : true;
    }

    public void OutsideControlClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!DropDownElement.IsMouseOver && !DisplayColorElement.IsMouseOver)
        {
            DropDownElement.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Control Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorPickerDropDown}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorPickerDropDown}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
                        <Rectangle Name="PART_DisplayColor"
                                   Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                   Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                   Fill="{Binding CurrentColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Popup Name="PART_DropDown"
                               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_DisplayColor}"
                               Width="{Binding ElementName=PART_DisplayColor}"
                               StaysOpen="True"
                               AllowsTransparency="True">

                            <Border Background="DodgerBlue"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    BorderBrush="AliceBlue"
                                    CornerRadius="0,0,0,15">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Rectangle Height="100"
                                               Width="98"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>

                        </Popup>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElement` attached event works only if you have enabled mouse capture using the `Mouse.Capture()` method. Therefore, you need to start mouse capture as soon as you open the popup. When mouse capture is active, `IsMouseOver` unfortunately cannot be used any longer; you have to check the mouse coordinates directly (see the method `IsWithin` in my sample below).

I have modified your code as follows (see places marked with `***`) and it worked for me:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = DisplayColorPart, Type = typeof(Rectangle))]
[TemplatePart(Name = DropDownPart, Type = typeof(Popup))]
public class ColorPickerDropDown : Control
{
    private const string DisplayColorPart = "PART_DisplayColor";
    private const string DropDownPart = "PART_DropDown";

    private Rectangle _displayColorElement;
    private Popup _dropDownElement;

    public Rectangle DisplayColorElement
    {
        get { return _displayColorElement; }
        set
        {
            _displayColorElement = value;
            InitalizeDisplayColorElement();
        }
    }

    public Popup DropDownElement
    {
        get { return _dropDownElement; }
        set { _dropDownElement = value; }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(ColorPickerDropDown),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public Brush CurrentColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(CurrentColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentColorProperty, value); }
    }

    static ColorPickerDropDown()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty
            .OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorPickerDropDown),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorPickerDropDown)));

    }

    public ColorPickerDropDown()
    {
        Mouse.AddPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementHandler(this, OutsideControlClick);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (DisplayColorElement == null) DisplayColorElement = GetTemplateChild(DisplayColorPart) as Rectangle;
        if (DropDownElement == null) DropDownElement = GetTemplateChild(DropDownPart) as Popup;
    }

    private void InitalizeDisplayColorElement()
    {
        if (DisplayColorElement == null) return;

        DisplayColorElement.AddHandler(Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
                                       new RoutedEventHandler(DisplayColorClick),
                                       handledEventsToo: true);
    }

    private void DisplayColorClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownElement.IsOpen = DropDownElement.IsOpen ? false : true;
        if (DropDownElement.IsOpen) // ***
        {                           // ***
            Mouse.Capture(this);    // ***
        }                           // ***
    }

    public void OutsideControlClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsWithin(DropDownElement.Child, e) && !IsWithin(DisplayColorElement, e)) // ***
        {
            DropDownElement.IsOpen = false;
            Mouse.Capture(null); // ***
        }
    }

    // *** Is mouse within the bounds of the UI element?
    public static bool IsWithin(UIElement element, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement elem = element as FrameworkElement;
        return (elem == null) ? false :
            new Rect(0, 0, elem.ActualWidth, elem.ActualHeight).Contains(e.GetPosition(element));
    }
}
```

Please also note that there is a small typo in your XAML. The line

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=PART_DisplayColor}"
```

should be

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=PART_DisplayColor, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Though I had to alter it a little. 1)Instead of starting captured in DisplayColorClick. I had to start capture When the mouse left the popup. 2) In OutsideElementClick I had to release mouse capture regardless of were the mouse located. I found out that I needed to change it when I started adding elements to popup but because of mouse capture I was unable to click any of them.